# Stack theoretic image?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-stacks

If $X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ is a morphism of schemes then the scheme theoretic image of $f$ is the smallest closed subscheme $Z \subset Y$ through which $f$ factors through.

Is this notion defined for algebraic stacks (at least under reasonable assumptions)?  If so, can someone provide a reference?

Comment: This definition in the scheme case is problematic because it is not local on the base (consider $\coprod {\rm{Spec}}(k[x]/(x^n)) \rightarrow \mathbf{A}^1_k$). So it seems better to just focus on qcqs $f$, where (as in EGA) you can *define* it to correspond to $\ker(O_Y \rightarrow f_{\ast}(O_X))$ (quasi-coherent since $f_{\ast}(O_X)$ is, as $f$ is qcqs), and then show by local calculation that this has the desired topological space and mapping property. Similar arguments work for Artin stacks. So the upshot is: consider requiring $f$ to be qcqs.

Comment: In fact qc is enough, in either the scheme or Artin stack context.